# ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification. Shiny FlexDashboard Regression Model Not working

Tags: r, machine-learning, shiny, leaflet, flexdashboard

I'm getting the error message when trying to deploy my shiny flexdashboard that was created with r markdown. Can anyone help? My code is below. Thank you! The data is [saved here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-IqLCkODQ3eDWAy7vmaCJj8ImERqajwj?usp=sharing)

The "submit" function seems to be the issue, I read in the random forest model I created so a data table could output once people enter in their desired input variables - but it doesn't seem to be working. The map and the accompanying data table works fine though.

```
library(readr)
library(tibble)
library(mlbench)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(ggthemes)
library(data.table)
library(geojsonR)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(flexdashboard)
library(reshape2)
library(lmtest)
library(htmltools)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(lsr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(knitr)
library(crosstalk)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

setwd("~/SPRING 2022/Data Science for Public Policy/FinalProject/new_DataSets")

risk_map <- readRDS("risk_map.rds")

model <- readRDS("model.rds")

variables <- c("dissim_19","Total_Pop20", "pct_adultsWchild_PH",  "mean_pov_idx", "mean_lbr_idx", "mean_trans_idx","recap","CDBG_perCapita")
```

## Fair Housing Plan Risk by County

### Row {data-height=400}

#### Map of Risk Prediction for Fair Housing Plans by County

##0 high risk, 1 medium risk, 2 low risk

```
#color and for na
pal <- colorFactor(
  palette =  c("#f03b20", 
               "#feb24c",
               "#ffeda0"), 
  domain = risk_map@data$predicted_outcome,
  na.color = "grey" # desired color for NA polygons on map
)

pal_noNA <- colorFactor(
  palette =  c("#f03b20", 
               "#feb24c",
               "#ffeda0"), 
  domain = risk_map@data$predicted_outcome,
  na.color = NA
)

risk_popup <- paste("<strong>Predicted Fair Housing Plan Risk Level: </strong>", 
                     risk_map@data$predicted_outcome,"<br><strong>County Name: </strong>", 
                     risk_map@data$county_name, "<br><strong>Total 2020 Population: </strong>",
                     risk_map@data$Total_Pop20, "<br><strong>CDBG Funding per Capita: </strong>",
                    risk_map@data$CDBG_perCapita,"<br><strong>2019 White to Non-White Dissimilarity Index: </strong>",
                    risk_map@data$dissim_19)

risk_map %>%
  leaflet::leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  setView(lat = 39.8283, lng = -98.5795, zoom = 4) %>%
  addPolygons(stroke = TRUE,
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              fillOpacity = .8,
              color = ~pal(predicted_outcome),
              weight = 0.5,
              popup = risk_popup) %>%
  # addAwesomeMarkers(data = results_points,
  #                  lat = ~X,
  #                  lng = ~Y,
  #                  icon = awesome,
  #                  popup = results_popup) %>%
  #                  #fillColor = "black",fillOpacity = 0.5,stroke = F)
  leaflet::addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal_noNA,
            values = ~predicted_outcome,
            title = "Predicted Risk of Fair Housing Plan Outcome by U.S. County",
            opacity = 1) %>%
  leaflet::addMeasure()
```

### Row {data-width=600}

#### Predictive Model Results

```
a <- 1:34
remove <- c (6, 18, 21:29, 31:33)

renderDT(
  risk_map@data,
  fillContainer = TRUE,
    filter = "top",server = FALSE,
    extensions = c('Buttons', 'Scroller'),
      options = list(
        dom = 'Blfrtip',
        buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
        scrollY = '600px',
        #scroller = TRUE,
        fixedColumns = TRUE,
        columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets = a[! a %in% remove]))
        # columnDefs = list(
        #   list(
        #     visible = FALSE,
        #     targets = c(6, 18, 21:29,31:33)
          ),
  colnames = c(
      "County Name" = "NAMELSAD",
      "State" = "State",
      "Dissimilarity Index 2019" = "dissim_19",
      "2020 Population" = "Total_Pop20",
      "% of Adults w/ Children" = "pct_adultsWchild_PH",
      "Total CDBG Funding" = "total_amt_cdbg",
      "Mean Poverty Index" = "mean_pov_idx",
      "Mean Job Prxmity Index" = "mean_lbr_idx",
      "Mean Transit Index" = "mean_trans_idx",
      "More than 4 RECAPs" = "recap",
      "AFH Submitter" = "AFH.Lead.Entity",
      "CDBG Funding per Capita" = "CDBG_perCapita",
      "Real Plan Outcome" = "real_outcome",
      "Predicted Plan Outcome" = "predicted_outcome"
    )
 )
```

## Generate Predicted Risk by County

### Column {data-width=600}

#### Enter in Indicators to Predict Fair Housing Plan Outcome by County

```
# dissim_19 #input
# Total_Pop20 #input
# CDBG_perCapita  
# pct_adultsWchild_PH #slider
# mean_pov_idx #slider
# mean_trans_idx #slider
# mean_lbr_idx #slider
# recap #yes or no multiple choice

sidebarPanel(
    HTML("<h3>Enter in all input variables for your county to predict outcome of AFH<h4>"),
    numericInput("dissim_19",
         label = "White to Non-White Dissimilarity Index",
         value = 34.58177),
    numericInput("Total_Pop20",
         label = "Total Population in 2020",
         value = 2149031),
    sliderInput("pct_adultsWchild_PH",
         label = "Percent of Adults w at Least One Child in all of the County's Public Housing",
         min = 0, max = 97, value = 1, step = 0.2),
    numericInput("mean_pov_idx",
         label = "Mean Poverty Index Score",
         value = 35.00000),
    numericInput("mean_trans_idx",
         label = "Mean Transportation Index Score",
         value = 39.000000),
    numericInput("mean_lbr_idx",
         label = "Mean LBR Index Score",
         value = 1500000),
    checkboxInput("recap", "Does the County have more than 4 census tracts designated as a RECAP? If Yes, click here", TRUE),
    numericInput("CDBG_perCapita",
         label = "Total CDBG Funding Amount per Capita",
         value = 1500000),
    
    actionButton("submitbutton", "Submit", class = "btn btn-primary")
  )
  
  mainPanel(
    tags$label(h3('Status/Output')), # Status/Output Text Box
    verbatimTextOutput('contents'),
    tableOutput('tabledata') # Prediction results table
    
  )

  
####################################
# Server                           #
####################################

server<- function(input, Output, session) {
  
  # Input Data
  datasetInput <- reactive({  
    
    df <- data.frame(
      Name = c("White to Non-White Dissimilarity Index",
               "Total Population in 2020",
               "Percent of Adults w at Least One Child in all of the County's Public Housing",
               "Mean Poverty Index Score",
               "Mean Transportation Index Score",
               "Mean LBR Index Score",
               "Total CDBG Funding Amount per Capita"
               ),
      Value = as.character(c(input$dissim_19,
                             input$Total_Pop20,
                             input$pct_adultsWchild_PH,
                             input$mean_pov_idx,
                             input$mean_trans_idx,
                             input$mean_lbr_idx,
                             input$CDBG_perCapita
                             )),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    Outcome <- 0
    df <- rbind(df, Outcome)
    input <- transpose(df)
    write.table(input,"input.csv", sep=",", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
    
    test <- read.csv(paste("input", ".csv", sep=""), header = TRUE)
    
    Output <- data.frame(Prediction=predict(model,test), round(predict(model,test,type="prob"), 3))
    print(Output)
    
  })
  
  # Status/Output Text Box
  Output$contents <- renderPrint({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) { 
      isolate("Calculation complete.") 
    } else {
      return("Server is ready for calculation.")
    }
  })
  
  # Prediction results table
  Output$tabledata <- renderTable({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) { 
      isolate(datasetInput()) 
    } 
  })
  
}

####################################
# Create the shiny app             #
####################################
#shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I feel that a code sample that starts with 32 library statments and then references files on your local machine is neither *minimal* nor *reproducible*.  This probably explains why you've received no suggests eight hours after posting.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help you reformat your question in a more user friendly manner.

Comment: noted @Limey I uploaded the data, but I'm new here and not sure what info is needed even after reviewing that post.